# Enlarge a 2d plot of f(x,y) while keeping the moiré patterns at the same size

Tags: multivariable-calculus, data-analysis, image-processing

I have some function $z=f(x,y)$ with $x,y,z$ real numbers. I wrote a script that generates a $600\times 600$ pixels plot of this function for, say, $0 < x < 1$ and $0 < y<1$, by mapping z to some color gradients. Now, because $f(x,y)$ is somewhat convoluted, the plot contains some nice moiré patterns that I find esthetically pleasing. Therefore I'd like to make a bigger version of this plot, say $3000\times 3000$ pixels, still with $0 < x < 1$ and $0< y <1$. Unfortunately when I do this the obvious way (by just calculating more points), the moiré fringes become much narrower and the result is not as interesting as the original.

So my question: is there a way to generate the bigger plot and still keep the moiré patterns at the same size as the original plot?

Comment: What about just interpolating the image up to 3k x 3x?

Comment: Consider asking at [dsp.se]